# Removing the broken package completely affects other packages

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg, dependencies

I was trying to install mega using dpkg and now, I have a **broken** package in my system, and when I run the Synaptic Package Manager and click on "Mark for complete removal" on the package, it gives me a warning box that says this will affect other packages.

[image]

The broken package is megasync:

[image]

Also, I am seeing this annoying white dash sign in a red circle on the top-right of my screen, and it says:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
> The error message was :'Error:BrokenCount>0'. This usually means that
> your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
> ..

Now, how should I go about it and remove the broken package completely from the system without messing up my system?

Edit:

`sudo apt update`

```
voidRealm@voidRealm:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                          e
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal InRelease                                                                            
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                     
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                   
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                      
Hit:7 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                             
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                                           
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Err:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.0 Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 99.86.42.60 443]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/apps/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`sudo-apt upgrade`

```
voidRealm@voidRealm:~$ sudo apt upgrade 
^Citing for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4557 (synaptic)... 16s
```

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using?  Please update your question and add the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. The error tells you to run `apt-get` in a terminal to see what is wrong.  So what did you learn when you did that?

Comment: I updated my question. I think there's some problem when I run `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: The `mongodb` repository is not found. You have also installed quite a few PPAs.  Do you know what they are all for and do you still use the software associated with them?

Comment: No, I don't know what they are for, but I use `mongodb` and it works fine.

Comment: linked: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed/) | [Are PPAs safe to add to my system...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

Comment: What's wrong with `mongodb` in official Universe repositories?  Why would you use a PPA for this software?  FYI: not just `mongodb` but also `simplescreenrecorder`, `obs-studio`, and `neofetch` are all available in Ubuntu repositories, without having to add a PPA.

Comment: I've removed all the PPAs that you have mentioned, but I'm not sure about `ubuntuhandbook1`. Is it safe to remove this? Also, I don't see `mongodb` PPA here. https://imgur.com/er5QUkN

Comment: I have no idea what is `ubuntuhandbook`, but if it's served by PPA then it is NOT part of Ubuntu.  The *mongodb* PPA is the one you have highlighted that says *mongodb*...  If you use the software you better make backups before uninstall/reinstall

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic misunderstanding:

To apt, a *broken* package does NOT mean that it's corrupt or defective. It's merely an *incompatible version*.

Generally, DON'T try to remove or uninstall "broken" packages. Sometimes you can, but sometimes, doing so will remove other packages. It's that apt dependency chain.

This kind of error usually occurs when folks read advice on the internet about how to get the newest or latest software.

The best way to fix the problem is to undo whatever changes you made: Restore the original Ubuntu repositories and remove the non-Ubuntu sources and PPAs that provided the broken package(s). Then it's usually possible to tell apt to (re-)install the compatible version of the broken package, which solves the problem.